# System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, fileloadexception

I have got this error when using Enterprise Library 3.1 May 2007 version. We are developing a product and have a common lib directory beneath the Subversion Trunk directory

<>\Trunk\Lib\  into which we put all the third party DLLs. Inside this we have Microsoft\EnterpriseLibrary\v3.1 in which we have copied all the dlls from \Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library May2007\bin. Everything was working properly until one of the developers installed the source code on this machine. There were some dlls copied at the end of the source code installation and once that was done, he is not able to run the project anymore. He always gets this error

**'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'**

What is the problem here? I thought that when the source code was installed it was just supposed to build everything and copy in the bin directory within the source code parent directory. Also we have copied the Dlls from Microsoft Enterprise Library May 2007\bin directory into our product development directory and references into our project with a copylocal flag set to true.

Can anyone help me out here

RK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to get that when I developed against the signed version of the dll and deployed where only the unsigned version was available.

Also, [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx).  EVERY.  TIME.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the error lies in the developer having compiled the code against the unsigned source code compilation he has.

Make sure he adds the reference to the signed DLLs before compiling his code.

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, **PublicKeyToken=null**

should be something like:

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, **PublicKeyToken=fa03fef243232**

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check the Assembly- and FileVersion of the dll. if they do not match this exception can occur.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) to get started with assembly loading debugging.

In short you need to check the Fusion log for more information.

> For a "The located assembly's manifest
>   definition with name [yourAssembly]
>   does not match the assembly reference"
>   message (for hresult
>   FUSION_E_REF_DEF_MISMATCH,
>   0x80131040): The Fusion log will say
>   which part of the assembly reference
>   failed to match what was found. It
>   will be the assembly name, culture,
>   public key (or token) or version (if
>   the found assembly was
>   strongly-named).